# Posix regular expression not working in C

Tags: c, regex

This is my first time working with regex in C and I am having some trouble. I am trying to replicate a syntax that is used in `sed`, namely the `s/findthisstring/replacewiththis/g` where `findthisstring` has to be present and `replacewiththis` does not.

The regex I came up with is `^s/(.*)/(.*)/g$`

Here it is in my code

```
int verifyPattern(char *pattern) {
    regex_t regex;
    int reti = regcomp(&regex, "^s/(.*)/(.*)/g$", 0);

    if (reti) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    reti = regexec(&regex, pattern, 0, NULL, 0);
    if (!reti) {
        puts("Match");
    } else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
        puts("No match");
    } else {
        puts("Regex error");
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I believe the part that is messing up is the `.+`. If I replace it with `.*` everything is fine. Anyone know a work around for this??

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a test case to show what does not work.

Comment: Why are you escaping the forward slash in the regex. The `/` is not a metacharacter in any regex engine. Also, it's not this simple to find embedded regular expressions unless you know how to parse regular expressions.

Comment: Try `const char *str_regex = "^s/((\\\\.|[^\\\\/]+)+)/(.*)/g$";`

Comment: No match using the test string `s/s/s/g`. Also I added how I am using it in my code

Comment: So, you do not want to actually extract, but check if the full string matches? Also, you forgot to use `REG_EXTENDED`. Your pattern allows `"s/s\/s/g"`

Comment: Try this one raw: `^s/(?:\\[\S\s]|[^/\\]+)+/[^/\\]*(?:\\.[^/\\]*)*/g$` stringed: `"^s/(?:\\\\[\\S\\s]|[^/\\\\]+)+/[^/\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^/\\\\]*)*/g$"` And basically you're not parsing a regex but a delimited form of a string. I.e. there is no validation this is even a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the `REG_EXTENDED` flag to allow `$` in the pattern. Also, your regex would allow too many `/.../` sections. What you need is to match either an escape sequence or a char other than `/` and `\`:

```
int reti = regcomp(&regex, "^s/(\\\\.|[^\\\\/]+)+/(\\\\.|[^\\\\/]+)*/g$", REG_EXTENDED);
```

See the [C demo](https://ideone.com/h2gjY9)

Basically, I replaced `.` with `(\\.|[^\\/]+)` pattern matching either an escape sequence (`\\.`) or (`|`) one or more characters other than `\` and `/`.

Here is a list of tests:

```
verifyPattern("s/s/s/g");//Match
verifyPattern("s/s//g");//Match
verifyPattern("s//s/g");//No Match
verifyPattern("s/s\\/s/g");//No match
verifyPattern("s/s\\/s/text/text/text/g"); // No match
```